# Using mustache.js to add a content-container for all pages of a static website

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

I want to build a static website where the content of every page is surrounded by the same content-container (navbar, footer, etc). To do that i want to use a templating engine like mustache.js to define my content-container and then render the template with the pages content inserted into the content-area of the template.

This is what i have in mind:

```
// Template
<h1>Website</h1>
<p>Navbar here</p>
<div class="content-area">{{{content_html}}}</div>
<p>Footer here</p>
```

The problem i am stuck with is where to put the different parts. The only solution that comes to my mind is:

- Put Template and Rendering/Insertion code into a `render_template.js` file
- Put the content of the page into a `site_content.html` file
- Call the render and insertion functionality while passing the correct content html from the actual `site.html`

Is there a way to put the content HTML into the actual `site.html` and use that for rendering the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the purpose of mustache. MustacheJs should be used to create element templates which are completed by variables values from a js object, not by full html pages (for example the template is the html structure of a user detail page and the variables which are inserted by mustache are the infos specific for the user like first-name, last-name,... In this case we can re-use the same template to display different users).

In your case if you can't use a dynamic language (like php, python or whatever), I would do this a bit different.

I would make separate html pages for each redondant part of your page (ex: header, navbar, footer). Then I would make all of your content pages where you will let a build process include the redondant parts (for exemple with GruntJS you can use this plugin : https://github.com/vanetix/grunt-includes)

Another way would be to use a js framework which handle component templating and includes, but this seems to be very complicated if you just need to include some html parts in pages.

Comment: This sounds a lot better than what i had in mind. I tried getting things set-up for the last hour, but it didn't feel like it was working out. I will go with the build-process generation, makes the whole thing easier to understand.